# switch off ebay javascript warning

Tags: javascript, css, firefox

I am most of the time using browsers with JavaScript switched off, and no pictures. At Ebay they give me a warning message("Please activate JavaScript") that stays right in the middle of the screen - is there a way to turn that off?  This seems to be css styling:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-touch" lang="de">

<head></head>
<body class="sz1200 full-width LV FIREFOX FIREFOX_35 FIREFOX_35_0">
    <noscript class="nojs">
        <div class="nojs-msk"></div>
        <div class="nojs-msg shdw"></div>
    </noscript>
    <div id="Head"></div>
    <div id="Body"></div>
    <div id="Foot"></div>
    <div id="HtmlFrags"></div>
    <div id="JSDF"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried disabling css (Disable CSS 1.0 for Firefox) but that works on all elements -  what makes the page unreadable. 
Can I make Firefox ignore just those two classes?

Comment: Use AdBlock to block the element or delete it in the HTML inspector

Comment: @JacobGray hence the adblock suggestion.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, and no you shouldn't.

Comment: Enable js and the warning goes away

Answer (score 2):

You could create a userscript to do this.

```
GM_addStyle ('.nojs {display: none;}');
```

**[Grease Monkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/)** | **[Userscripts how-to](http://userscripts-mirror.org/about/installing.html)**